# Keeping JSON Files Updated

Tags: javascript, json

I wanted to get some advice on handling a complex JSON file. It probably isn't complex, but I'm quite new to this and would like to get some advice to move forward with it.

I've got two JSON objects currently.

**providers.json**

```
{
  "providers" : [
    {
      "id" : 471756,
      "title" : "The Whittington Hospital",
      "services" : [
        {
          "id" : 362718,
          "title" : "Hernia Repair",

          "reviews" : [
            {
              "rating" : 5,
              "body" : "Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.",

              "user" : {
                "username" : "realph",
              }
            }
            ...
```

**services.json**

```
{
  "services" : [
    {
      "id" : 362718,
      "title" : "Hernia Repair",
    ...
```

Imagine I've pushed the Hernia Repair item in the `services.json` to the `providers` object, like shown above. How can I make sure this stays in sync. For example, say I make a change to the `title`, how can I make sure that change is updated on the `services` object, as well as the `providers` object.

Is there a best practice to dealing with stuff like this.

If anyone has any experience with stuff like this, I'd really appreciate some advice.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally this kind of thing is handled in a database rather than raw json files. It certainly can be done though. In both cases however you'll have to use whatever logic is updating the data to ensure the data stays in sync. Only update the data through interface x, and ensure that interface x updates both. In a database this would be stored in at least 3 separate collections: services, providers, and reviews, and any linking that needs to be done would be through foreign keys.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm planning to use Firebase for this. Would I be right in thinking that whenever a `service` item is updated, I could also run a function that looks for every instance of that `service` by its `id` and updates it? Or is there an easier way to keep it in sync?

Comment: you update the in-ram objects then stringify both to disk at the same time. one will have to write first, and if you crash at that exact moment, then the files will be out of sync, or worse. i find it safer to save a sibling file with a related filename, and once written, delete the orig and rename the sibling to the orig's name, and delete the sibling. that way, even if you crash at any point, you won't lose data.

Comment: If your data wasn't redundant, you wouldn't need to run that function that looks for every instance of service. That would mean storing services, providers, and reviews in separate files and then linking them together by id.

Comment: @KevinB Wow this sounds really complex. Could you point me in the direction of any reading material to get myself familiar with this sort of stuff?

Comment: Or, you could just go with one giant file, why do you need services to be stored separately?

Comment: @KevinB I guess it just made more logical sense to me, but feel free to correct me if I'm doing it all wrong here. There are going to be a hundreds of `services` that I will need to attach to multiple `providers`, that was my thinking.

Comment: I agree with KevinB that this is a data problem, specifically a normalization problems (see  rules for first order normalization here http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html).  If your data was normalized, then the title would only be in the services reference, not in both places.  To display a provider's services you would look up the title from the reference--no sync required.

Comment: @KevinB Do you know of any reading material that might explain on how to link multiple .json files together, by say an ID, like you mentioned??

Comment: I don't, and i've never attempted it myself because i've always had access to a relational database system for this kind of thing. Doing this with multiple json files would be essentially creating your own relational database system, at this point you might as well look into implementing mysql or mssql.